# Google Sheets: IF statement - If complex conditions are true, output another cell's data

Tags: sorting, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, percentage

In my Google Sheet, I have all my test scores, which I have averages of, by using `=AVERAGE()`. Out of these averages, I can see which is the highest by using `=MAX()` and the lowest by using `=MIN()`. I would like to create a code for a cell that:

1. Whichever the highest percentage is, it outputs the subject value (the column next to it).
2. Then, I would like another code (which I think I could code) that prints "Highest Average: *Subject* | *Percentage*"

What could I do?

[My Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQG6wj4SqNffqU1vK32kzF_lNkYM-qqwC3csNPCUw6fdI9AfOV-DIv8OqNS5bPI3BQYzxU7-wkVPExP/pubhtml#) ("Sheet 5" is the imported range). Same table is below:

[image: Image of Google Sheey]

| Percentage | Subject |
| --- | --- |
| 65.1428571428572% | Biology |
| 66% | Chemistry |
| 37.2549019607843% | Physics |
| 75% | French |
| 58.6206896551724% | Geography |
| 81.7058823529412% | English |
| 77.6923076923077% | Maths |
| 94.1741071428569% | Computer Science |
| 78.7435897436% | D&T |

Comment: link to your sheet is broken and your objective is hard to be understood. repair the link and include example of desired result there

Comment: I am not able to access your documet!

Comment: does this help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
={"Highest Average: "&JOIN(" | ", INDEX(TEXT(SORT({B:B, A:A}, 2, 0), {"@", "#.00%"}), 1));
  "Lowest Average: "& JOIN(" | ", INDEX(TEXT(SORT({B:B, A:A}, 2, 1), {"@", "#.00%"}), 1))}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, it says this: #ERROR!
"Lowest Average: "& JOIN(" | ", INDEX(TEXT(SORT({B:B, A:A}, 2, 1), {"@", "#.00%"}), 1))}

Comment: @taylor.2317 see: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tHbqmLKppp8QAV-XDjy2yuC2l_M7zQvJgllLMYcZeKk/edit#gid=253284437

Comment: I have requested edit access so I can show you what happens on my document

Comment: @taylor.2317 granted

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
=query(A:B,"select * order by A desc limit 1 ",0)
```

or

```
="Highest Average: "& query(A:B,"select B order by A desc limit 1 ",0)  &" | Percentage " &text(query(A:B,"select A order by A desc limit 1 ",0),"0.00%")
```

and

```
=query(A2:B,"select * where A is not null order by A asc limit 1 ",0)
```

or

```
="Lowest Average: "&
query(A2:B,"select B where A is not null order by A asc limit 1 ",0)  &
" | Percentage " &
text(query(A2:B,"select A where A is not null order by A asc limit 1 ",0),"0.00%")
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, for the 2nd code, I get "Highest Average:  | Percentage Lowest Average: Physics | 37.25%" as a result whilst the 1st one works fine...

Comment: I have updated my answer (for lowest %)

Comment: The lowest % was fine, it was the highest that said this: ⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀Highest Average: | Percentage Lowest Average: Physics | 37.25% (THE LOWEST IS FINE!)

Comment: Take a copy and tell me what is wrong https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zlqHr7WylGUZ5Odukm5oKIUL56M5vfma8n0i85qFImo/copy formulas in yellow background

Comment: The problem is the account that I'm using is owned by an organisation and I can't share outside of it...

Comment: can you upload my own spreadsheet mentionned in the previous comment. If not I have posted a screen shot!

Comment: Thanks, but the issue has been resolved :)